# QCustomPlot lagging when many points for multipleData

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I have problem that my multigraph plot lags when there is a lot of points.
I use separate thread to take data from deque and put on graphs.

How to make my plot to work more real-time?

If found that:
http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/performanceimprovement.html

but it is still not halping enough.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code. And explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you ploting every time you receive new data?

Comment: Code is quite compliated and big to paste any relevant part.

I have buffer on deque and every 10 samles ( changable) data is taken and displayed.

I have difficulty that when there is a lot of data on plot then it lags.
All other functionalities are ok. Only drag and zoom lags.

Comment: It's very hard to give a solution for that without seeing any code. One possible thing is, if you're doing `rescale` on each axis every time you plot, you might want to change it to `setScale` as you can see in [this example](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/realtimedatademo). It should be more efficient.  Maybe just paste relevant parts from your code - only things you suspect that might be the problem.